# load csv file into list

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a python script, it first writes a `list` to CSV file, after which immediately loads the CSV file into another `list`.

I tried separately only the code which writes `list` to CSV, it works,  the CSV file content is tab delimited, its content is like:

```
car house wife
```

But when put all together:

```
import csv

// write list to CSV file, it works!
the_list=["car","house","wife"]
the_file = open("my_file.csv", 'w+')
writer = csv.writer(the_file, delimiter='\t')
writer.writerow(the_list)


// read CSV file & load into list
my_file = open("my_file.csv", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter='\t')
my_list = list(reader)
print(my_list)
```

I get an empty list printed out : `[]` , what is wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you've shown us. Are you sure this is the entirity of the code that you are running?

Comment: Have you tried supplying an absolute path to `open` ?

Comment: OK, I put the full code here now. Please take a look.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not closing the file that you are writing to so the reading finds no data to read. You can use the `with` statement to make sure that the file is closed.

```
import csv

# write list to CSV file, it works!
the_list=["car","house","wife"]
with open("my_file.csv", 'w') as outfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow(the_list)


# read CSV file & load into list
with open("my_file.csv", 'r') as my_file:
    reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter='\t')
    my_list = list(reader)
    print(my_list)
```

If you do that the reading works fine.

```
➜  python test.py
[['car', 'house', 'wife']]
```

Comment: he could also throw a the_file.close() and my_file.close() after each processing step.

Comment: true, I think that using `with` is a good pattern anyway though :)

Comment: I agree, just stating he could short fix it that way if he doesn't know what 
**with** does

Comment: By the way, how to get rid of the double square brackets `[[... ]]`? Now, if I do `my_list.append("something")`, I ended up with `[['car', 'house', 'wife']] 'something'` , I mean the element is appended outside the outer `]`

Comment: The reader returns an iterator that returns one list per row. So if you actually only want to append to the first row just do `my_list[0].append("something")`

Comment: @k-nut, thanks! It also would be nice to add this in your answer.